# How to build kernel backport on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, backport

I installed CentOS 7 on a Macbook Pro early 2015 with Broadcom BCM43602 wifi chip. I've tried all other methods by digging through the CentOS documentation about wifi setup. I finally came to realize that a potential solution is to compile backports for the `brcmfmac` kernel module.

### Running kernel

`Linux centos7.localdomain 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 31 16:04:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

### What I did

- Downloaded and unzipped backport from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/
- Read backport [documentation](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation/packaging)
- Ran `make defconfig-brcmfmac`
- Ran `make` and was greeted with errors.

### Log of commands and output below.

```
[admin@centos7 backports-4.0.1-1]$ make mrproper
  CLEAN   /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/.tmp_versions
[admin@centos7 backports-4.0.1-1]$ make defconfigs-brcmfmac
Generating local configuration database from kernel ... done.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `defconfigs-brcmfmac'.  Stop.
make: *** [defconfigs-brcmfmac] Error 2
[admin@centos7 backports-4.0.1-1]$ make defconfig-brcmfmac
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
[admin@centos7 backports-4.0.1-1]$ make
make[5]: `conf' is up to date.
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/compat/main.o
In file included from include/linux/rcupdate.h:43:0,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/rcupdate.h:3,
                 from include/linux/srcu.h:33,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from include/linux/memory_hotplug.h:6,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:824,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/module.h:3,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/compat/main.c:1:
/home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/completion.h:14:20: error: redefinition of ‘reinit_completion’
 static inline void reinit_completion(struct completion *x)
                    ^
In file included from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/completion.h:3:0,
                 from include/linux/rcupdate.h:43,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/rcupdate.h:3,
                 from include/linux/srcu.h:33,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from include/linux/memory_hotplug.h:6,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:824,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/backport-include/linux/module.h:3,
                 from /home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/compat/main.c:1:
include/linux/completion.h:86:20: note: previous definition of ‘reinit_completion’ was here
 static inline void reinit_completion(struct completion *x)
                    ^
make[6]: *** [/home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/compat/main.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [/home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1/compat] Error 2
make[4]: *** [_module_/home/admin/Documents/backports-4.0.1-1] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

**What I am missing here?**

Answer (score 0):

4.0.1?

centos 7 is based on 3.10 kernels, except Red Hat applied plenty of custom patches and the codebase already diverged from upstream 3.10. There is a chance an upstream patch will work anyway due to luck and/or kabi guarantees.

But the real question is why are you trying to use centos 7 on a dekstop matchine. If you want to use a distro tied to red hat you can try fedora. Otherwise try ubuntu.

Comment: I have several reasons of why I am trying to do it. (1) Some commercial software I use was developed for Red Hat 7. (2) They are slow on updating the code for newer kernels. (3) (Came when I read about bacports) Want to explore and try backports and kernel customization. (4) Ubuntu is not an option in this case for me. And the compatible Fedora version is 20, which is not supported any more: https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28Linux-distribution%29

Comment: You can create a container with appropriate userspace. rhel/centos kernels are not going to have features not present upstream. In some extreme cases the upstream kernel may not be bug-to-bug compatible, but that's reasonably unlikely. In worst case just get a vm. patch backporting is not a task for people without a firm grasp on kernel development. it has a misleading apparent triviality to it as often the patch you want will compile just fine with little to no effort, despite possibly being completely broken.